# (Resolve) Insert to bigquery not same row number input

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata

I using google bigquery API for insert data to bigquery

```
public void upload(Collection<Bucket> buckets){
log.finer("Uploading " + buckets.size() + " buckets to bigquery");
List<Rows> rows=new ArrayList<Rows>();
for (  Bucket bucket : buckets) {
TableRow row=new TableRow();
row.set("uploaded",System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000f);
row.set("codepoint",bucket.getKey().getCodepoint());
row.set("namespace",bucket.getKey().getNamespace());
row.set("kind",bucket.getKey().getKind());
row.set("op",bucket.getKey().getOp());
row.set("query",bucket.getKey().getQuery());
row.set("time",bucket.getKey().getTime() / 1000f);
row.set("reads",bucket.getReads());
row.set("writes",bucket.getWrites());
TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows rowWrapper=new    TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows();
rowWrapper.setJson(row);
rows.add(rowWrapper);
}
TableDataInsertAllRequest request=new      
TableDataInsertAllRequest().setRows(rows);
String tableId=tablePicker.pick();
try {
TableDataInsertAllResponse response=bigquery.tabledata().insertAll(insightDataset.projectId(),insightDataset.datasetId(),tableId,request).execute();
if (response.getInsertErrors() != null && !response.getInsertErrors().isEmpty()) {
  throw new RuntimeException("There were errors! " + response.getInsertErrors());
}
}
 catch (  IOException e) {
throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
}
```

My problem:

I using 2 server call function insert to bigquery same time, same account bigquery.

Example:

Server A: have 500 rows

Server B: have 400 rows

It's right if insert to google bigquery 900 rows

But when I check in google bigquery have 1300 rows.

When I test with 1 server then It insert right (500 rows with server A and 400 rows with server B).

Can you help me this trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should properly set the [insertId](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) propery. You need to find out how to do that with the library that you use.

```
public TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows setInsertId(java.lang.String insertId)
[Optional] A unique ID for each row. BigQuery uses this property to detect duplicate insertion requests on a best-effort basis.
Parameters:
insertId - insertId or null for none
```

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows.html#setInsertId(java.lang.String)

Comment: I using GUIID for insertID, but It don't duplicate. Do you know why?